# getEscaper() is deprecated on Ui Component Listing Column Actions on Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

getEscaper() is show deprecated, Actually, I followed a tutorial to create Magento grid and actions on it, but the getEscaper() shows deprecated.

So i go over one of Magento 2 default extension Magento CMS,

vendor/magento/module-cms/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/PageActions.php

on line number 82, it shows the same.

Any idea what is this?

If Default Magento extension have this issue so then where I get the solution to it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `escapeHtml(` as an alternative to `getEscaper()`.

If you check current develop branch  https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/PageActions.php#L82

then you have found that they have already changed to `escapeHtml(`

Comment: on that line, i found

$title = $this->getEscaper()->escapeHtml($item['title']);

but still getEscaper() is being used.

still, show the deprecated message.

Comment: I don't think the class `Magento\Framework\Escaper` is deprecated. Might be Magento asking to   use object manager directly.

Comment: it means if want to use escapeHtmlthen you have inject the class to your construct and access the public functionh ofn  that class.]